# Temperature of AdS-Schwarzchild black holes? How physics is the same for different temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft, thermal-field-theory

The five dimensional Schwarzchild-AdS black brane's metric is given by

$$
ds^2_5=-\left(\frac{r}{L}\right)^2h(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{\left(\frac{r}{L}\right)^2h(r)}+\left(\frac{r}{L}\right)^2(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2),
$$
$$
h(r)=1-\left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^4
$$
the horizon is located at $r=r_0$.

Hawking temperature is as follows :
$$
T=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{r_0}{L}$$
It is argued (for example : Natsuume,AdS/CFT duality user guide chapter 7) that under the scaling $x^{\mu}\rightarrow ax^{\mu}$, $r\rightarrow \frac{r}{a}$, the black hole metric is invariant if we define the new horizon by $r'_0=ar_0$. so we can always scale the horizon radius and blackhole with different horizon radii are equivalent.
From the AdS/CFT duality, this means that all temperatures are equivalent and the physics is the same(except for zero temperature).

I can not see how different temperatures have the same physics. For example energy density and entropy density are as follows:

$$
s=\frac{\pi^2}{2}N^2T^3,
$$
$$
\epsilon=\frac{3}{8}\pi^2N^2T^4
$$
which have a clear $T$ dependence.

Comment: That's a technical term which refers to the fact that there is no phase transition in the theory. In the absence of the phase transition, the physics is the same in all scales (the boundary theory is scale invariant).

Comment: @SG8 Thanks, Is the boundary theory scale invariant at the finite temperature?

Comment: The scale invariance here means that the whole bulk theory remains invariant under dilatation (which is a part of conformal symmetry). This is the classical interpretation of scale invariance. For the boundary gauge theory, a quantum mechanical interpretation for the "scale invariance" is needed (since the theory is a kind of QFT). In quantum gauge theories, the appearance of any renormalization scale breaks the scale invariance. In your case, the $\beta$-function of the boundary theory vanishes so it's a scale invariant theory.

Comment: This means the physical laws do not change if scales of length, energy, or other variables, are multiplied by a common factor. However, in particle physics, there is another interpretation for the scale invariant: in such theories, the strength of particle interactions does not depend on the energy of the particles involved. This is equivalent to the absence of any  renormalization scale. So, your question in the comment "Is the boundary theory scale invariant at the finite temperature?" does not have a precise meaning. BTW, I hope you get a complete answer to the question soon.

Comment: Also, be careful about about the scale invariance in the statistical field theories. In such cases, near the critical point the theory is scale invariance since the fluctuations occur at all length scales.

Comment: @SG8 thank you so much, yes I know that N=4 super Yang-Mills theory has a zero beta function at zero temperature, but Is it true for finite temperature?

Comment: As far as I remember, N=4 super Yang-Mills theory has a zero beta function at all temperatures since it is quantum mechanically scale invariant (the number of field species in this theory implies this property). It means there is no coupling constant which runs with the change of energy. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SG8 thank you so much, I thought that temperature break the scale invariance of any conformal symmetry, because temperature break Lorentz symmetry and so conformal symmetry. but It seems that it is just a spontaneously symmetry breaking of the theory. Is it true? or in the bulk theory, black hole break conformal isometry of the metric, so we have not conformal symmetry of our theory.

Comment: I didn't get your previous comment. SBB crucially depends on the energy scale and I can find no reason for it to occur in an scale-invariant quantum field theory. Typically, in theories with SSB, a physical system in a symmetric state ends up in an asymmetric state (however, the entire Lagrangian is invariant under a specific symmetry but the lowest-energy states (sometimes called vacuum or ground states) do not respect that symmetry). I think, for pure N=4 SYM (without mass terms), no SSB can take place and, also in your case, the conformal symmetry does not break in any temperature.

Comment: @SG8 Thanks,  I think I need to think more about it.